# Common version of Office Interop DLL to support most version?

Tags: c#, dll, ms-office

I am working on Windows application. I have set functionality to export employee list to excel file. For that I have added Interop DLL Version 12.0.0.0. But when I install it with any system having Office 2003. it throws error.

Can anybody suggest me Version which can atleast work with Office 2007, 2010, 2013 and 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 12.0 is for Office 2007, so it will work for 2007+. You will need to reference a 10.0 dll to have it work with Office 2003.